# Stop Chrome from automatically downloading files without a prompt on Android 11

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading, files, android-11

I'm using Chrome for Android (93.0.4577.82) on Android 11. On Chrome on PC and Macs, it is possible to always prompt the user when the browser attempts to download a file. However, on Chrome for Android, it just automatically downloads files without prompting once I click on a link every time.

I've blocked auto-downloads in "Site Settings" and specified both the "Ask when to save files" and "Ask where to save files" options under Downloads.  However, the issue persists.

Any idea if I'm missing something? Can't seem to find a workable solution online yet.

Comment: A crude way could be to deny storage permissions to Chrome. It will be forced to ask and you can deny //I couldn't find any flags for it in the current version of Chrome

Comment: Just to clarify in case this is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919), is the problem really about automatically downloading PDF files without prompt? Just to make sure since if you expect the PDF to be opened directly in Chrome for Android, note that Chrome for Android doesn't have an in-built PDF reader, so it needs external PDF reader apps to open it (and also downloads the PDF files first).

Comment: Hey @andrew, I'm trying to prevent Chrome from auto-downloading PDFs. Even after changing the settings, the behaviour still persists in which Chrome just downloads PDFs and opens it on another app. Any idea why this might be the case? Tried beeshyams solution above by clearing cache and also storage for good measure, but still same behaviour. Interesting that you say Android doesn't have an inbuilt reader. I'm running stock Android, but it's able to open the PDF somehow? I haven't downloaded any 3rd party PDF apps

Comment: @AlbertKinterman thanks for the clarification. I mentioned "Chrome for Android" since it's not the same as Chrome for PC where users can view the PDF inside the browser. Though, Android also doesn't have an inbuilt PDF viewer, must be other pre-installed apps like Google Drive which does provide PDF viewer to other apps.

Comment: Ok sure thanks for the heads up, I think it's opening it via Drive. However, can I prevent Chrome on Android from auto downloading PDFs and other files tho? This works for Chrome on PC and Macs. Seems like a strange security flaw to prevent auto downloads on the internet.

Comment: Hey @Andrew T., any updates on this? I can't seem to prevent Chrome on Android from downloading files automatically. It just automatically downloads files once I click on a link everytime even though I've blocked automatic downloads and set it to ask everytime. Any idea what the issue might be? I'm running stock Android 11.

Comment: @AlbertKinterman sorry, I'm not sure I can help on this one. Also, since you mentioned "other files", I decided to update the question so that it's not only about PDF files anymore. Feel free to rollback if it's incorrect and/or [edit] the question to add more information.

Comment: Ok sure, thanks for the edit, not sure about all files but definitely experiencing this with PDFs. Are you experiencing the same thing? Updated to the latest version of Chrome (94.0.4606.61) and still seeing the same behavior.